# Smoke is not casting shadows in Eevee

Tags: rendering, smoke-simulation, shadows, visibility

Smoke is not casting shadows in Eevee render.
The blend file is given below.

[image: e]

[image]

Comment: Eevee cannot do that. Volumetrics are quite limited. Recommended reading: [**Cycles vs Eevee, 15 limitations on real time rendering**](https://cgcookie.com/articles/blender-cycles-vs-eevee-15-limitations-of-real-time-rendering)